# On hover another layer move if that layer mose hover then hover stop

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hover is kind of funny as in this code a new layer .hide which get appear when hover as it transition it response differently  I try diffent thing like hide:hover +img{} and other if anybody know about it please help is there is any hack in this issue.

Thing is there is two layer first layer should fade Opacity and another layer transition with animation that is only word. Which is .hide Class that but if then i hover on .hide class which transition when hover cause issue.,

Right Now i using with z index different But then Text hide behind the back of image.

```css
.catalog {
  overflow:hidden;
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  margin:2px;
}


.catalog img:hover{
  
  transition: transform 500ms , opacity 500ms 0ms ease-in-out;
  transform: scale(1.3);
  opacity: 0.3;
}
.hide{
  z-index:0;
  display:block;
  font-size: 10px;
  position:relative;
  top:-50px;
  transition: font-size 500ms , top 500ms 0ms ease-in-out;
  width:100%;
  background: #6c6c934d;
background-size: 300px 300px;
color: #13436c;
}
.catalog img:hover + .hide {
  font-size:50px;
  top:-300px;
  padding-bottom:50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex wrap center space-around jcenter">
  <div class="catalog">
    <img src="https://ikrent.com/include/image/refrigerator.png" height="300px">
    <label class="hide"> Refrigerator</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am confused on what you are asking here, but for starters, you have `label` misspelled. Also, `label` isn't the right element for what you are doing. You should use `figure` and `figcaption` for something like this.

Comment: thanks i will try this

Comment: That not work , 
Thing is there is two layer first layer should fade and another layer transition with animation that is only word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue happens because you add the styles on img:hover, simply, by default, these events are triggered for the selector itself or one of its children, in this case, the image and the div.hide are siblings, to avoid this behavior you can update your code to add these styles on catalog:hover, which is a parent of both, so whenever you hover on of them, you will be hovering the parent too

```css
.catalog {
  overflow:hidden;
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  margin:2px;
}


.catalog:hover img{
  
  transition: transform 500ms , opacity 500ms 0ms ease-in-out;
  transform: scale(1.3);
  opacity: 0.3;
}
.hide{
  z-index:0;
  display:block;
  font-size: 10px;
  position:relative;
  top:-50px;
  transition: font-size 500ms , top 500ms 0ms ease-in-out;
  width:100%;
  background: #6c6c934d;
background-size: 300px 300px;
color: #13436c;
}
.catalog:hover .hide {
  font-size:50px;
  top:-300px;
  padding-bottom:50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex wrap center space-around jcenter">
  <div class="catalog">
    <img src="https://ikrent.com/include/image/refrigerator.png" height="300px">
    <label class="hide"> Refrigerator</label>
  </div>
</div>
```